# How to get the column number of matching text?

Tags: column

In the help there is `looking-at` function which should populate `match-data` which could be accessed with `match-end` function.

So I have the text :

`1. hello world`

The cursor is on `1` and I issue the command `M-:` `(looking-at "1\\. ")`, the result is `t`.

Now immediately I do `M-:` `(match-end 0)` and expect to get `3` but I get `7 (#o7, #x7, ?\C-g)`

Is this approach incorrect? Should I use smth else to get the column number?

PS
If I use a little bit more fancy regex in `looking-at` then I get crazy numbers from `match-end` - 653 or even 1432. Which are definitely not a column numbers.

*Update*
if the text is a single line as above I get correct result.

`1. hello world
1. hello world`

On the first line I get `4`
On the second line I get `19`

Looks like char count + 1, not the column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs including the installed packages does itself some fancy matching between the two calls of `M-:`. With `(match-data)` and relatives you get the match data of the last search operation. That search-op was most certainly not yours.

If you want to get the end of your `looking-at` operation you should use the following command.

<kbd>M-:</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> `(progn (looking-at "1\\. ") (match-end 0))` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

This gives you the character positon of the end of the match in the buffer.

If you want to get the column number you can use the following command instead:

`(progn (looking-at "1\\. ") (- (match-end 0) (line-beginning-position)))`

Please be aware that this does also count invisible characters.

An alternative that tries hard to give you the real display column by not counting invisible characters is:

`(save-excursion (looking-at "1\\. ") (goto-char (match-end 0)) (current-column))`

Still this may fail if some stretch of the text has the `display` text property. E.g., you can display one space as three spaces with

<kbd>M-:</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> `(insert (propertize "\n1. " 'display "1.   "))` <kbd>RET</kbd>

and the alternative approach above will still output 3 for the newly inserted line even if the single space character takes the space of three display columns.

Comment: I have got `672 (#o1240, #x2a0, ?ʠ)`

Comment: Hmm, I got different results depending on position of the text

Comment: @MaximKim Yes, `looking-at` and the corresponding match data deliver buffer positions, not columns. If you want the column subtract `(line-beginning-position)`. That is still fragile since there might be invisible characters.

Comment: This does not answer the question as posed, which is about getting the column number. Please consider adding an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: @Drew: In the first line it gives you the column number. And that was the OP's original test.

Comment: Yes, I know. Still, the question is about column #. And as such it, and the answer, are more helpful if general, i.e., for any line.

Comment: @Drew: Done. Hope that's it.